# Fetching data from server with promise using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

How do I fetch table from db with promise. I have created a service and http call with promise. I have checked the console and the url is not getting called. I am not sure this is the eight way of creating service return a http promise

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <base href="/">
        <title>The Single Page Blogger</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@*" data-semver="0.12.1" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/module.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/style2.css" />
        <script>

            app.controller('tableController', function ($log, $scope, tableService)
            {
                $scope.customerTable = [];
                var promise = tableService.fetchTable();
                promise.then(function (data)
                {
                    console.log("Your name is: " + data);
                    $scope.customerTable = data;
                });
            });

            app.factory('tableService', function ($http)
            {
                return
                {
                    fetchTable: function()
                    {
                        return $http.get('<%=request.getContextPath()%>/GetTable.do');
                    }
                }
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container" id="main"><br/><br/>
            Search: <input type="text" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search">
            <div ng-controller="tableController">
                <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                        <th style="font-size: 13.3px">Card number</th>
                        <th style="font-size: 13.3px">First name</th>
                        <th style="font-size: 13.3px">Opening balance</th>
                        <th style="font-size: 13.3px">Withdrawal</th>
                        <th style="font-size: 13.3px">Deposit</th>
                        <th style="font-size: 13.3px">Closing balance</th>
                        <th style="font-size: 13.3px">Tx date</th>
                        <th style="font-size: 13.3px">Usage type</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="data in filteredTodos| filter: search">
                        <td>{{data.CARD_NUMBER}}</td>
                        <td>{{data.FIRST_NAME}}</td>
                        <td>{{data.OPENING_BALANCE}}</td>
                        <td>{{data.WITHDRAWAL}}</td>
                        <td>{{data.DEPOSIT}}</td>
                        <td>{{data.CLOSING_BAL}}</td>
                        <td>{{data.TXDATE}}</td>
                        <td>{{data.USAGE_TYPE}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <pagination 
                    ng-model="currentPage"
                    total-items="customerTable.length"
                    max-size="maxSize"  
                    boundary-links="true">
                </pagination>
                <br/><br/><br>
                <button class="form-control btn btn-success" type="submit" ng-click="fetchTable()">Load Table Data</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service makes the promise but does not deliver, try adding the $q service into yours like this:

```
app.factory('tableService', function ($http, $q) {
    return {
        fetchTable: function() {
            // the $http API is based on the deferred/promise APIs exposed by the $q service
            // so it returns a promise for us by default
            return $http.get('<%=request.getContextPath()%>/GetTable.do')
                .then(function(response) {
                    if (typeof response.data === 'object') {
                        return response.data;
                    } else {
                        // invalid response
                        return $q.reject(response.data);
                    }
                }, function(response) {
                    // something went wrong
                    return $q.reject(response.data);
                });
        }
    };
});

app.controller('tableController', function ($log, $scope, tableService)
{
    $scope.customerTable = [];

    $scope.getData = function() {
        var promise = tableService.fetchTable();

        promise.then(function (data)
        {
            console.log("Your name is: " + data);

            $scope.customerTable = data;
        });
    }
});

<div ng-controller="tableController" ng-init="getData()">
```

Comment: There's no controller? How do I call it in html? just call the `fetchTable()` with button click?

Comment: Tried this: `<button type="submit" ng-click="fetchTable()">Load Table Data</button>` still not working

Comment: Your controller remains the same, although I would add your service call intro a method and call ng-init on the div

Comment: You do not need the $q service when returning a promise like he does. Only if you want to create a deferred promise manually and hooking a resolve and reject to it.

Comment: Should work though, especially with the init so his code does not execute on controller creation

Comment: Its working now but I have a one more problem now. Its not rendering the table data more than 15rows. I have about 25rows

Comment: Any way I will post this as a new question

Comment: @MrDrishu Why my code didn't work? only difference I can see is $q?

Comment: I guess this part?  `if (typeof response.data === 'object') {
                                        return response.data;
                                    } `

Comment: you where missing 2 things to call .then() in the service so it can deliver its promise and setting up the init so the controller code does not run at object contruction but when its needed, after resources are loaded. The $q differ helps with executing the code after resource load.

Comment: One more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31135224/unable-to-fetch-more-than-15-rows-in-angularjs based on current question

Answer (score 1):

```
app.controller('tableController', function ($log, $scope, tableService)
    {
        $scope.customerTable = [];
        var promise = tableService.fetchTable();
        promise.then(function (data)
        {
            console.log("Your name is: " + data);

            $scope.customerTable = data;
        });
    });
```

This should do it. You were returning the data before setting the `$scope.customerTable`. As a matter of fact, why are you even returning `data`? You can't return something from a callback like that. I've removed that line also.

Comment: http url is not getting called. I changed my code as you have said. Did I write the service correctly?

Comment: @kittu Can you put a console log before you return the $http.get? just to make sure that the function itself is running correctly. Try adding a .catch after your then() also and log the error to see if it says anything.

Comment: Like this: `catch (function(error) {
                        console.log("An error occured: " + error);` ??

Comment: Did the fetchTable function run? Did you try that?