# Unable to fetch more than 15 rows in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have about 25rows in the response data. After using pagination, it fetches 5 rows per each page and there are only 3 pages coming up.

code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <base href="/">
        <title>The Single Page Blogger</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@*" data-semver="0.12.1" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/module.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/style2.css" />
        <script>

            app.factory('tableService', function ($http, $q) {
                return {
                    fetchTable: function () {
                        // the $http API is based on the deferred/promise APIs exposed by the $q service
                        // so it returns a promise for us by default
                        return $http.get('<%=request.getContextPath()%>/GetTable.do')
                                .then(function (response) {
                                    if (typeof response.data === 'object') {
                                        return response.data;
                                    } else {
                                        // invalid response
                                        return $q.reject(response.data);
                                    }
                                }, function (response) {
                                    // something went wrong
                                    return $q.reject(response.data);
                                });
                    }
                };
            });

            app.controller('tableController', function ($log, $scope, tableService)
            {
                $scope.filteredTodos = []
                        , $scope.currentPage = 1
                        , $scope.numPerPage = 5
                        , $scope.maxSize = 5;

                $scope.customerTable = [];

                $scope.getData = function () {

                    var promise = tableService.fetchTable();

                    promise.then(function (data)
                    {
                        console.log("Your name is: " + data);

                        $scope.customerTable = data;
                        $scope.$watch("currentPage + numPerPage", function () {
                            var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage)
                                    , end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;

                            $scope.filteredTodos = $scope.customerTable.slice(begin, end);
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container" id="main"><br/><br/>
            Search: <input type="text" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search">
            <div ng-controller="tableController" ng-init="getData()">
                <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                        <th style="font-size: 13.3px">Card number</th>
                        <th style="font-size: 13.3px">First name</th>
                        <th style="font-size: 13.3px">Opening balance</th>
                        <th style="font-size: 13.3px">Withdrawal</th>
                        <th style="font-size: 13.3px">Deposit</th>
                        <th style="font-size: 13.3px">Closing balance</th>
                        <th style="font-size: 13.3px">Tx date</th>
                        <th style="font-size: 13.3px">Usage type</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="data in filteredTodos| filter: search">
                        <td>{{data.CARD_NUMBER}}</td>
                        <td>{{data.FIRST_NAME}}</td>
                        <td>{{data.OPENING_BALANCE}}</td>
                        <td>{{data.WITHDRAWAL}}</td>
                        <td>{{data.DEPOSIT}}</td>
                        <td>{{data.CLOSING_BAL}}</td>
                        <td>{{data.TXDATE}}</td>
                        <td>{{data.USAGE_TYPE}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <pagination 
                    ng-model="currentPage"
                    total-items="customerTable.length"
                    max-size="maxSize"  
                    boundary-links="false">
                </pagination>
                <br/><br/><br>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the value of `customerTable.length`? Is it 25 or 15?

Comment: There are 25 rows of data in the database

Comment: I mean, is your `controller` fetching the exact value (25)?

Comment: yes its fetching what ever values present in db

Comment: Try my posted answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `items-per-page="5"` in your `pagination` tag.

**E.g.**

`<pagination 
    ng-model="currentPage"
    items-per-page="5"
    total-items="customerTable.length"
    max-size="maxSize"
    boundary-links="false">
</pagination>`

Hope it helps.